Issues with Salesforce GraphQL and Date fields
So I am noticing some issues with using Date fields in aggregate GraphQL queries in Salesforce (LWC or graphql service).
Issue 1:
Filtering where Date not equal to null does not work:
query contacts {
    uiapi {
         aggregate {
                Contact (
                   where: {
                        and: [
                            {Birthdate: {ne: null}},
                        ]
                    },
                      groupBy: {Birthdate: {group: true}}
                ) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            aggregate {
                                  Birthdate {
                                  value
                                }
                                Id {
                                    count {
                                        value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

Results
{
  "data": {
    "uiapi": {
      "aggregate": {
        "Contact": {
          "edges": [
            {
              "node": {
                "aggregate": {
                  "Birthdate": {
                    "value": null
                  },
                  "Id": {
                    "count": {
                      "value": 26
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "node": {
                "aggregate": {
                  "Birthdate": {
                    "value": "2024-11-20"
                  },
                  "Id": {
                    "count": {
                      "value": 1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "errors": []
}

Note the fact we have a count for null.
The equivalent query in SOQL
SELECT Birthdate, COUNT(Id)
FROM Contact
WHERE Birthdate <> NULL
GROUP BY Birthdate

Result


Issue 2:
Grouping by custom Date fields results in an error, WHEN the field contains values and nulls:
ie some records have the field populated some records do not
Query
query contacts {
    uiapi {
         aggregate {
                Contact (
                   where: {
                        and: [
                            {Date_of_Birth__c: {ne: null}},
                        ]
                    },
                      groupBy: {Date_of_Birth__c: {group: true}}
                ) {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            aggregate {
                                  Date_of_Birth__c {
                                  value
                                }
                                Id {
                                    count {
                                        value
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

Result
{
  "data": {
    "uiapi": {
      "aggregate": {
        "Contact": null
      }
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "ErrorType": "DataFetchingException"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "column": 17,
          "line": 4
        }
      ],
      "message": "Exception while fetching data (/uiapi/aggregate/Contact) : Couldn&#39;t find apiElementInfo for field: Date_of_Birth__c",
      "paths": [
        "uiapi",
        "aggregate",
        "Contact"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Update:
Working with Salesforce Support, I believe I have a work around for this issue.  Basically using function to break the date into its parts, and then when processing the date need to reformat it to build the usable date again.
aggregate {
    Date_of_Birth__c {
        calendarYear {
            value
        }
        calendarMonth {
            value
        }
        dayInMonth {
            value
        }
    }
    Id {
        count {
            value
        }
    }
}

I have a case open with Salesforce currently for Issue 2, but issue 1 I only just noticed, will probably add it to the case unless someone has any ideas how to resolve this, though in reality I would just ignore those records in my use of the data.
Support Documentation:
Aggregate Support for Field Types

On the date filtering, if I do a gte query it does work
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/graphql/guide/filter-fields.html#date-datetime-and-time-field-types
eg
Birthdate: {gte: "2024-01-01"}

About the first issue, you should filter null or not null Date fields using an object with a "value" property equals null, i.e.

Asking for not null values: Birthdate: { ne: { value: null } }
Asking for null values: Birthdate: { eq: { value: null } }

By the way, since you have only one where clause, you don't need the and operator.
Request:
query contacts {
    uiapi {
        aggregate {
            Contact(
                where: {
                    Birthdate: { ne: { value: null } }
                },
                groupBy: {
                    Birthdate: { group: true }
                }
            ) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        aggregate {
                            Birthdate {
                                value
                            }
                            Id {
                                count {
                                    value
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

About the second issue, I think you did good opening a case with Salesforce.

Thanks Ruben, missed the 'value:' part.
This is just a cut down query from what I am working on, the 'and' was just carry over from trying to diagnose what was happening.

FYI - added a work around for the issue 2, still think the main issue needs to be fixed by Salesforce
